# incorrect button width using grid in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, grid

Somehow the buttons placed using grid method will be much bigger than the cell width defined by `columnconfigure`. I tried to place some test labels in the same way, and it worked as expected. Is there any way to get correct button width like these labels did?

[image]

Below is the simplified code to the question:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.ttk import *

root = tk.Tk()   

style = Style()
style.theme_use('clam')    
style.configure('TestLabel1.TLabel', background='red')
style.configure('TestLabel2.TLabel', background='green')
style.configure('TestLabel3.TLabel', background='blue')
style.configure('Buttons.TButton')

output_path = tk.StringVar()
output_path.set('test')
settings = Frame(root, width=500, height=200)
settings.pack_propagate(0)
settings.pack(side='top')
chart_preset_frame = LabelFrame(settings, text='Chart Parameter Preset', padding=(5, 5, 5, 5))
chart_preset_frame.pack(expand=True, fill='x', pady=10, side='top')
chart_preset_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=6)
chart_preset_frame.columnconfigure(1, weight=2)
chart_preset_frame.columnconfigure(2, weight=2)        
output_path_input = Entry(chart_preset_frame, textvariable=output_path, width=20)
output_path_input.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky='EW', ipady=5)

output_load_btn = Button(chart_preset_frame, text='Load...', style='Buttons.TButton', command=None)
output_load_btn.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='EW', padx=0, pady=5)

output_save_btn = Button(chart_preset_frame, text='Save As...', style='Buttons.TButton', command=None)
output_save_btn.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky='EW', padx=0, pady=5) 

# for label test
# label_test_1 = Label(chart_preset_frame, text='test', style='TestLabel1.TLabel')
# label_test_1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='EW')
# label_test_2 = Label(chart_preset_frame, text='test', style='TestLabel2.TLabel')
# label_test_2.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='EW')
# label_test_3 = Label(chart_preset_frame, text='test', style='TestLabel3.TLabel')
# label_test_3.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky='EW')
           
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`weight` is just a guideline to the layout manager how to distribute available spaces.  Since there is no widget in cell (row 1, column 0), it may not get the required space.

It can be enforced by adding `uniform=1` to those `columnconfigur(...)`:

```py
chart_preset_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=6, uniform=1)
chart_preset_frame.columnconfigure(1, weight=2, uniform=1)
chart_preset_frame.columnconfigure(2, weight=2, uniform=1)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: More correctly, weight tells grid how to distribute _extra_ space.

Comment: wow it works perfectly! I was about to give up and use another frame for the buttons yesterday.  Thank you!!